# update key value in xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but here is what I would like to be able to do.

My xml file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<content>
  <option name="0">Yes</option>
  <option name="1">No</option>
  <option name="2">Maybe</option>
</content>
```

I would like to update only one node at the time, for example:
Replace word "Maybe" with something else, where value == 2. So it needs to search for "option name="2" and replace word Maybe with user input.

Comment: Look up DOMDocument, XPath, etc: http://bit.ly/1l85McN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `simplexml`and `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// get the node
$node = $xml->xpath("/content/option[@name = '2']");

// change it
$node[0][0] = "Hello!";
```

see it working: https://eval.in/127855